# How do you use elasticsearch in python to search over all indices?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, search

Here is my code:

```
def search(term):
    s = Search().filter('match_phrase', title=term)
    response = s.execute()
    return response
```

Looking at the function, title is the name of one of my indices. How do I change it so instead of only searching over one index, it searches over all of my indices?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this by enumerating your indices:

```
def search(term):
    s = Search(index=['index1', 'index2']).filter('match_phrase', title=term)
    response = s.execute()
    return response
```

or like this using a wildcard

```
def search(term):
    s = Search(index='index*').filter('match_phrase', title=term)
    response = s.execute()
    return response
```

Comment: Thanks! However when I try the first solution using the list of indices, I'm getting a NotFoundError where it telle me "no such index". Any ideas? Also, If you look at the end of the line, there's "title=term" where term is the input I'm trying to query and title is the name of one of the indices. I'm still confused how I indicate there that I want to search over all of the indices and not only the "title" index. Any ideas?